# How do I know if JArray entries are type string or type float (or whatever)?

Tags: c#, json.net

I've got a json document that looks like this:

```
{
 "default": ["auto", 1.0]
}
```

where either of the array entries could be a (predefined) `string` or a `float` value. I had assumed that using the `(float?)` cast would return `null` in the cases where it was a `string`, but apparently I'm wrong. So what's the right way to go about doing this?

Just to be clear, this fails with the error message:

```
float? x = (float?)property.Value[0];
```

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Can not
>   convert String to Single.

Of course, I could always just catch that exception, but I don't think that's the intended solution.

Comment: You can try using `Single.Parse()` or `Single.TryParse()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, with only a couple more minutes of thinking, I came up with this obvious solution:

```
if (property.Value[0].Type == JTokenType.Float)
{
    x = (float)property.Value[0];
```